# RTL8190 wireless card unclaimed

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek, troubleshooting

I have recently installed Ubuntu and I'm having problems with my (RTL8190) card.

I followed the steps listed here - [Ubuntu Help: Troubleshooting Wireless](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html).
After using the command `sudo lshw -C network` I got the following output:

```
*-network         
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: 06
serial: 10:78:d2:73:9f:0d
size: 10Mbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
resources: irq:42 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:f8fff000-f8ffffff memory:f8ff8000-f8ffbfff

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: RTL8190 802.11n Wireless LAN
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 1
bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
version: 00
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=64 mingnt=32
resources: ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fbfff000-fbffffff
```

I proceeded to install the **`ndisgtk`** package and downloaded the `net819xp.inf` driver.

Using the windows wireless drivers app, I selected the .inf file but it said there was an error. I attempted to select it again but it said it was already installed. When I run the original command again it still lists the card as `UNCLAIMED`.

Anyone know how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the sources for the network card from realtek. I have these:

r8168-8.029.00 (maybe from here [realtek r8168-8.029.00](http://code.google.com/p/r8168/downloads/detail?name=r8168-8.029.00.tar.bz2&can=2&q=); can't remember exactly. I cherish the sources I have on my machine... :-)

And then follow instructions in this post:

[RTL8111/RTL8168 fix](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022411&page=11)

It's great. The Realteks are never working out of the box.. for years. At least, not for me. I always need a fix. So, I fixed it again after installing 12.04.