# Ubuntu 13.04 can't see my Realtek wifi card

Tags: wireless, 13.04, dell, realtek

In my Dell Vostro 220 I've got a Realtek wifi card about which Terminal says

```
03:01.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.1
```

Windows 7 uses it fine, but Ubuntu can't seem to see it. I set up a wifi connection in the Network prefs but it doesn't show up in the drop-down network menu in the upper right corner of the screen. I find nothing in **System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**.

I update the OS very regularly.

I've downloaded drivers from Realtek's site, but I'm new to Linux and I have no idea which version of an archive to download nor what to do with all those files in the archive once I extract it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Editor's note, 13th August 2017 - driver link in original answer returns 404. Replaced with link to the Github repository's releases page (latest is 14th Feb this year). Installation procedure is the same, but given the passage of time, YMMV from OP's.</sub>

---

Realtek doesn't provide a Linux driver for this card :(

So we are left with two options

- Use some driver that matches the hardware design
- Use `ndiswrapper` (using windows driver in linux, I would never recommend it except as a last resort.

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153293/35775), you can use the r8168 driver with it.

So based on that answer, download the latest driver package [from here on GitHub](https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168/releases)

Now open a terminal, and `cd` to the location you saved the file to; for example, if it was the `Downloads` directory:

```
cd Downloads
```

Next unpack the archive and `cd` into the created directory (check the name with `ls` and/or use tab completion if these wildcards don't work for you)

```
tar -xf r8168*
cd r8168*[0-9]
```

Now run the installer as root

```
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

And reboot your machine.

Comment: thank you. your instructions worked and Terminal returned no error messages, but i've restarted my machine and deleted and recreated a wifi connection in the Network Connections pane and nothing seems to have changed. there's still no wifi option in the Network preferences, and the wifi network connection i added doesn't work any better now than it did before. neither is there anything in the "Additional Drivers" pane.

got any other ideas? either way, i appreciate your time. thanks.

Comment: apparently ndiswrapper is already installed. would that be causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My way around it was to get my old Linksys wireless router and install [Tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) on it, connect to it through my NIC and configure the router as a wireless client and connect it to my wireless network that way.

If you dont have a old Linksys router, you can check your local goodwill store; last time I was in one I saw 4 in there for about $5 each.